# Screen timeouts

Tags: display, settings

I have an issue that after 5 minutes of not using my laptop I goes into sctreen saver and then I have to re enter my password. I cant find a setting to change this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What do you see when you go into System Settings, Security and Privacy, then click Locking on the left side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings, Select the power options under the Hardware Category.

There you can choose the screen time-out duration and the duration when your laptops suspends in Elementary OS terms when plugged in or on battery.

[image: Screenshot of Power options in System Settings on Elementary OS]

Thanks,
Animish